# How can we hide connection settings in Anywhere Work execution application from user?

Tags: maximo-anywhere

Hi I am suppose to hide a setting in Anywhere when I tried to Comment that setting in Application build.js file which contains all settings its giving me error while previewing. Anyone has any idea on this?

Comment: Hi there - can you help me understand which connection settings you are trying to hide? Generally, you can go into the app.xml and comment out anything that you don't want to show under the view tag, but depending on where your connection settings are there may be some additional places apply changes to in the platform folder.

Answer (score 0):

WorkExecution-> app-feature.properties file change

connection.settings.enabled=true to connection.settings.enabled=false